# What is the trouble with this code? Why is it showing: Debug assertion failed! _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-debugging

What is wrong in the code?

What change should I make in the code to make it defensive?

### Array.h

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_H_
#define _ARRAY_H_

class Array
{
private:
    int * m_ArrayContainer;

public:
    Array();
    void AllocateMemoryOfSize(int size);
    void DeallocateMemory();
    void SetElementsIntoTheIndex(int index, int value);
    int GetElementFromIndex(int index);
    int operator [] (int index);
    ~Array();
};

#endif
```

### Array.cpp

```
#include "Array.h"
#include <iostream>

Array :: Array()
{
    this->m_ArrayContainer = NULL;
}

void Array :: AllocateMemoryOfSize(int size)
{
    this->m_ArrayContainer = new int[size];
}

void Array :: DeallocateMemory()
{
    delete [] this->m_ArrayContainer;
}

void Array :: SetElementsIntoTheIndex(int index, int value)
{
    this->m_ArrayContainer[index] = value;
}

int Array :: GetElementFromIndex(int index)
{
    return this->m_ArrayContainer[index];
}

int Array :: operator [] (int index)
{
    return this->m_ArrayContainer[index];
}

Array :: ~Array()
{
    this->DeallocateMemory();
}
```

### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Array.h"

int main()
{   
for(int i=0 ; i<250 ; i++)
{
    Array array1;
    array1.AllocateMemoryOfSize(3);
    array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(0, 10);
    array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(1, 10);
    array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(2, 10);

    /*array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(0, NULL);
    array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(1, NULL);
    array1.SetElementsIntoTheIndex(2, NULL);*/

    array1.DeallocateMemory();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Since your edit, tl;dr. Try to post a minimal, compilable example that exhibits the error. Since this isn't homework and your not studying CS you should probably just use a std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor calls `DeallocateMemory()` for the second time and that leads to `delete[]` being called for the second time with the same address which triggers undefined behavior. To guarg against this you should change

```
void Array::DeallocateMemory()
{
    delete [] this->m_ArrayContainer;
    this->m_ArrayContainer = 0;
}
```

so that when the destructor is called and it calls `DeallocateMemory()` a null pointer is `delete[]`d which is a no-op.

Btw you should at least prohibit copy constructor and `operator=` in your class by declaring them private and leaving unimplemented - your class doesn't support memberwise copying.

Comment: This solution is correct. Don't just give up. Try to locate the problem. Put some index checks in your array classes.

Comment: @BROY would you mind posting what you did to solve the problem?  Did you use what sharptooth suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Because in each iteration of the loop you call `delete[]` twice on the same allocated array. Once via an explicit call to `DeallocateMemory` and once via the call in the destructor of `Array`.